# Await calls inside a normal context manager?

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio, contextmanager

EDITED:
Ran a piece of code to try this myself, and got:
`"await" allowed only within async function.`
This makes sense, since a function that defines `@contextmanager` is a non-async function.

Is it possible to have an `await` call inside a `contextmanager`?

For example:

```py
@contextmanager
def sample_contextmanager():
    # some synchronous calls
    yield
    # some synchronous calls
```

```py
with sample_contextmanager:
    await some_coroutine()
```

Comment: when you tried this, what happened?

Comment: Just tried, and got an error saying: 
`"await" allowed only within async function`. 
Should've tried it myself before asking. Thanks!

Comment: Now that I think about it, it makes sense that running a coroutine inside a subroutine wouldn't work. Forgot that a contextmanager was just a method after all!

Comment: This has nothing to do with the context manager. Whatever function you're using the context manager in needs to be defined with `async def` and needs to be run via the event loop.

Comment: Yup you're right. When I mentioned contextmanager, I meant it in the context of a function that is defined by `@contextmanager` and not `@asynccontextmanager`.